# Default value for hdfs dfs -ls

Tags: java, hadoop

Why is `hdfs dfs -ls` different from `hdfs dfs -ls /`.

What is the default value of `hdfs dfs -ls`

Answer (score 0):

The default is your hdfs user's home dir, something like `/user/$USER` (where $USER is the user you're logged into at the shell, nothing to do with hdfs).

Comment: I'm not sure how/if you can edit it. I'm not sure what you mean by where the value is stored. I believe the hdfs user is just whatever OS user you run the "hdfs" command as. So, if your terminal login is rshah, then your hdfs home is /user/rshah, and that's what `hdfs dfs -ls` will list. Some parts of this may be configurable, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs dfs -ls /` displays the folders for root provided if you have the root access. All the users created will have folders in `hadoop dfs -ls /user/$user`

It is advisable to use `hdfs fs -ls /` as the use of `dfs` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default value in the hadoop.sh  file in the bin directory.